# Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat Performance

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat7, tomcat8

I am developing Microservices API for my application. I started with Spring Boot application. I created two artifacts - **"business code with embedded tomcat"** and **"business code without embedded tomcat"**.

When I compare the performance results, I can see that the "non-embedded tomcat" (i.e. executing on standalone tomcat) gives good output because of native execution.

So basically **what is the difference between the embedded tomcat and the standalone tomcat regarding implementation?**

How the performance varies between two executions?

Comment: How you did the tests? Could you explain? Thanks.

Comment: @Rudge: Using Jmeter i simulated load on both scenarios. I am using camel in my business-code. At the end of transaction, i am printing message history which displays route info with execution time. when i compare execution time for both secanrio at least i am getting 20ms average delay on embedded tomcat .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found out actual root cause of this issue.

APR (Apache Portable Runtime) plays important role in tomcat thread execution.

**By Default, embedded tomcat executes NIO. NIO and BIO are Java based executions whereas APR is native execution. When we compare performance of NIO and APR, APR is pretty much faster.**

In fact all the Linux based tomcat bundles are shipped with APR libs under the tomcat lib folder.

After I enabled APR in embedded tomcat (i.e. Spring Boot) performance execution was same compared to standalone tomcat.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html

Comment: hi @Peter Jerald, could you please share me how you enable APR in embedded tomcat?

Comment: @Ace.Yin here is how: https://gist.github.com/andreldm/7f89a3279438467a0bd41e6c1249d014

Comment: Peter could you please provide me how did you enable APR in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

We can enable APR in springboot embeded tomcat by overiding the org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory and providing new org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector
with org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol protocol.

The below code might help to get it done.

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainerFactoryProd() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new 
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            // to create new directories and files and add them to Context
            return super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
        }
    };
    
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol");
    Http11AprProtocol protocol = (Http11AprProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
    connector.setProperty("compression", "on");
    // can also enable ssl and provide certificate details
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
    return tomcat;
}
```