# Spring boot documentation Update

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

Recently I have encountered a performance problem with spring-boot embedded tomcat. Later I found APR libraries improved the performance and execution problem.

I have update my comments in below link;

[Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319869/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-performance)

Is it possible to update this step in official documentation ?

Regards,
Peter Jerald.

Comment: Maybe ask pivotal on their site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want us to update in the official documentation but please create a request in [the Spring Boot issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) and we'll have a look. Thanks!